# inner join not working in DataFrame using Spark 2.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

My Data Set :-

```
emp dataframe looks like this :-
emp.show()

+---+-----+------+----------+-------------+
| ID| NAME|salary|department|         date|
+---+-----+------+----------+-------------+
|  1| sban| 100.0|        IT|   2018-01-10|
|  2|  abc| 200.0|        HR|   2018-01-05|
|  3| Jack| 100.0|      SALE|   2018-01-05|
|  4|  Ram| 100.0|        IT|2018-01-01-06|
|  5|Robin| 200.0|        IT|   2018-01-07|
|  6| John| 200.0|      SALE|   2018-01-08|
|  7| sban| 300.0|  Director|   2018-01-01|
+---+-----+------+----------+-------------+
```

2- Then I group by using name and took its max salary , say dataframe is grpEmpByName :-

```
val grpByName = emp.select(col("name")).groupBy(col("name")).agg(max(col("salary")).alias("max_salary")) 
grpByName.select("*").show()
+-----+----------+
| name|max_salary|
+-----+----------+
| Jack|     100.0|
|Robin|     200.0|
|  Ram|     100.0|
| John|     200.0|
|  abc|     200.0|
| sban|     300.0|
+-----+----------+
```

3- Then trying to join :-

```
val joinedBySalarywithMaxSal = emp.join(grpEmpByName, col("emp.salary") === col("grpEmpByName.max_salary") , "inner")
```

Its throwing

```
18/02/08 21:29:26 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 13.667672 ms
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`grpByName.max_salary`' given input columns: [NAME, department, date, ID, salary, max_salary, NAME];;
'Join Inner, (salary#2 = 'grpByName.max_salary)
:- Project [ID#0, NAME#1, salary#2, department#3, date#4]
:  +- MetastoreRelation default, emp
+- Aggregate [NAME#44], [NAME#44, max(salary#45) AS max_salary#25]
   +- Project [salary#45, NAME#44]
      +- Project [ID#43, NAME#44, salary#45, department#46, date#47]
         +- MetastoreRelation default, emp
```

I am not getting why its not working as when I check

```
 grpByName.select(col("max_salary")).show() 

+----------+
|max_salary|
+----------+
|     100.0|
|     200.0|
|     100.0|
|     200.0|
|     200.0|
|     300.0|
+----------+
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot notation is used to refer to nested structures inside a table, not to refer to the table itself.

Call the `col` method define on the `DataFrame` instead, like this:

```
emp.join(grpEmpByName, emp.col("salary") === grpEmpByName.col("max_salary"), "inner")
```

You can see an example [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html).

Furthermore, note that [`join`s are `inner` by default](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@join(right:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), so you should just be able to write the following:

```
emp.join(grpEmpByName, emp.col("salary") === grpEmpByName.col("max_salary"))
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure, hope can help:

```
val joinedBySalarywithMaxSal = emp.join(grpEmpByName, emp.col("emp") === grpEmpByName.col("max_salary") , "inner")
```